# A question about a theorem in 'Quantum dynamical semigroups generated by noncommutative unbounded elliptic operators'

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, unbounded-operators, semigroups-of-operators

I have asked this question [on MathSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2900658/a-question-about-a-theorem-in-quantum-dynamical-semigroups-generated-by-noncomm#comment5991401_2900658) and someone advised me to ask it here. The link is .

I'm studying the paper **Quantum dynamical semigroups generated by noncommutative unbounded elliptic operators** by Changsoo Bahn and Chul Ki Ko and Yong Moon Park [(arxiv link)](https://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/0505026v1).

I have a question on the proof (p.15) of theorem 3.1 (p.10) of this paper, in which a part of deduction goes as

> \begin{align}
> &[W^2-\sum_{l=1}^d(W_l)_l,W_k\partial_k+\partial_kW_k]\\=&[W^2,W_k\partial_k+\partial_kW_k]-[\sum_{l=1}^d(W_l)_l,W_k\partial_k+\partial_kW_k]\\=&-2W_k((W^2)_k-\sum_{l=1}^d(W_l)_{lk})
> \end{align}

where $W=(W_1,\cdots,W_d)$ is a function $:\mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}^d$, $(W_i)_k$ is the $k^{th}$ derivative of $W_i$ and $W^2=\sum_{i=1}^d (W_i)^2$.

I am stuck in the last equal sign, for which I think we need for $A,B \in \mathcal{D}$:

$$[A,B\partial_k+\partial_k B]=-2B(A)_k.$$

But my calculation for this goes as:

\begin{align}
&[A,B\partial_k+\partial_k B]+2B(A)_k\\=&AB\partial_k+A\partial_kB-B\partial_kA-\partial_kBA+2B\partial_kA-2BA\partial_k\\\not = &0
\end{align}

Am I missing something or is the paper wrong?

Comment: What are $W,W_{k}$?Is $W_{k}$ the partial derivative (in direction $k$) of $W$?

Comment: @Asaf sorry about the confusion. I've made some changes to the description of the question